# Como funciona a função atan2?

Tags: java, matemática, java-processing

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

> O ângulo deve ser escolhido para que ele sempre aponte diretamente para o *mouse*. Encontre o ângulo em relação ao eixo X (então 0 é reto para a direita e PI/2 é direto para cima).

Esse método é escrito da seguinte forma:

```
float getAngle() { 
  return atan2(height-mouseY, mouseX);
}
```

- Alguém pode me ajudar a entender esse método?
- Por que `height-mouseY` e `mouseX` como parâmetros?

Comment: Eu uso esse arco-tangente no texto da minha questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260764/64969 ; inclusive eu o contraponho perante o "arco-tangente 1"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vejamos o Javadoc do [método `atan2(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-), já traduzido para o português por mim:

> ```
> public static double atan2​(double y,
>                            double x)
> ```
>
> Retorna o ângulo *teta* da conversão das coordenadas retangulares `(x, y)` para as coordenadas polares `(r, teta)`. Este método computa a fase *teta* ao computar uma arco-tangente de `y/x` no intervalo *-pi* a *pi*. Casos especiais:
>
> - Se qualquer argumento for `NaN`, então o resultado é `NaN`.
> - Se o primeiro argumento é zero positivo e o segundo argumento é positivo, ou o primeiro argumento é positivo e finito e o segundo argumento é infinito positivo, então o resultado é zero positivo.
> - Se o primeiro argumento é zero negativo e o segundo argumento é positivo, ou o primeiro argumento é negativo e finito e o segundo argumento é infinito positivo, então o resultado é zero negativo.
> - Se o primeiro argumento é zero positivo e o segundo argumento é negativo, ou o primeiro argumento é positivo e finito e o segundo argumento é infinito negativo, então o resultado é o valor `double` mais próximo de *pi*.
> - Se o primeiro argumento é zero negativo e o segundo argumento é negativo, ou o primeiro argumento é negativo e finito e o segundo argumento é infinito negativo, então o resultado é o valor `double` mais próximo de *-pi*.
> - Se o primeiro argumento é positivo e o segundo argumento é zero positivo ou zero negativo, ou o primeiro argumento é infinito positivo e o segundo argumento é finito, então o resultado é o valor `double` mais próximo de *pi/2*.
> - Se o primeiro argumento é negativo e o segundo argumento é zero positivo ou zero negativo, ou o primeiro argumento é infinito negativo e o segundo argumento é finito, então o resultado é o valor `double` mais próximo de *-pi/2*.
> - Se ambos os argumentos são positivo infinito, então o resultado é o valor `double` mais próximo de *pi/4*.
> - Se o primeiro argumento é positivo infinito e o segundo argumento é negativo infinito, então o resultado é o valor `double` mais próximo de *3*pi/4*.
> - Se o primeiro argumento é negativo infinito e o segundo positivo é negativo infinito, então o resultado é o valor `double` mais próximo de *-pi/4*.
> - Se ambos os argumentos são negativo infinito, então o resultado é o valor `double` mais próximo de *-3*pi/4*.
>
> O resultado computado deve estar dentro de 2 ulps do resultado exato. Resultados devem ser semi-monotônicos.
>
> **Parâmetros:**
>
> `y` - a coordenada ordenada
>   `x` - a coordenada abscissa
>
> **Retorna:**
>
> O componente *teta* do ponto `(r, teta)` em coordenadas polares que correspondem ao ponto `(x, y)` em coordenadas cartesianas.

Ok, talvez você não entenha entendido nada da documentação, afinal de contas ela utiliza conceitos matemáticos um tanto complicados. Para entendê-la, vamos considerar isso:

- Esqueça os casos especiais, eles estão aí apenas para resolver indeterminações que ocorreriam em situações bem peculiares e incomuns.
- Esse negócio de 2 ulps é apenas uma forma de se especificar uma margem de erro. Isso existe porque a representação do `double` usa um número finito de bits (64), mas o resultado exato do `atan2` pode ser (e quase sempre é) um número irracional, e que portanto não tem como ser representado com exatidão em qualquer quantidade finita de bits. Esse negócio de semi-monotônico é para indicar que números muito próximos dentro da margem de erro não produzirão resultados em ordens inversas das esperadas. Entretanto, esses detalhes aqui não devem importar para o problema que você quer resolver.
- O método do Java trabalha com `double`s e não com `float`s. Imagino que o processing esteja disponibilizando uma `atan2` com `float`s por simplicidade. No entanto, seja como for o caso, o efeito prático será o mesmo.
- Observe que a ordem dos parâmetros é `y` e `x`, e não `x` e `y`.
- O `float` e o `double` mantêm o sinal do zero, diferenciando +0 de −0. Eles também podem representar +∞ e −∞ e uma coisa chamada `NaN`. Isso tudo provavelmente não vai ser importante para você. O motivo dessas coisas acontecerem é assunto para alguma outra pergunta.
- [*Teta*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%98) é o nome de uma letra grega: θ. Assim como [*pi*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0) é π.

A questão é que você tem que imaginar que temos o sistema cartesiano e o polar:

- No sistema cartesiano, você tem coordenadas `(x, y)` onde `x` é a distância entre o ponto que você tem e a linha **vertical** que passa pela origem (ou seja, o quanto que esse ponto está movido para os lados) e o `y` é a distância entre o ponto que você tem e a linha **horizontal** que passa pela origem (ou seja, o quanto que o ponto está movido para cima ou para baixo).
- Já no sistema polar, você tem coordenadas `(r, teta)` onde *`teta`* é a direção em que o ponto que você tem está a partir da origem e `r` é a distância até ele.

Se você estivesse em um campo plano, em busca de um tesouro enterrado, com um papel contendo as instruções para achá-lo em mãos, e nesse papel estivesse escrito, "*vire 60 graus para a esquerda e ande 500 metros*", isso seria uma orientação usando coordenadas polares. Mas se estiver escrito "*ande 250 metros para frente e então 433 metros para a sua esquerda*", então são usadas coordenadas cartesianas. As duas orientações chegam no mesmo lugar<sup>1</sup>, embora na primeira você vá percorrer uma distância menor.
<sup><sub>1: Na verdade há uma diferença de cerca de um centímetro. O valor correto seria 433,012701892... metros.</sub></sup>

No entanto, fica a pergunta:

> Se no papel estiver escrito que devo andar 250 metros para frente e então 433 metros para a minha esquerda, mas estou com muita pressa porque o tempo é curto e não posso andar mais que o necessário, como eu poderia saber que o que eu teria que fazer é virar 60 graus para a esquerda e então andar 500 metros?

A distância podemos resolver pelo teorema de Pitágoras. Temos que 250 metros e 433 metros são os catetos de um triângulo retângulo e o trecho a se percorrer é a hipotenusa. Logo:

> [image: a]
>   [image: b]
>   [image: c]
>   [image: d]

Arredondando-se o erro de um centímetro, deu 500 metros.

E agora que já sabemos a distância a percorrer, como podemos saber a direção?

Olhando para as coordenadas cartesianas, o `x` é a distância que eu percorreria para frente (ou para trás se for negativo) e o `y` é a distância que eu sigo para algum lado. Qual lado? Direita ou esquerda? O plano cartesiano normalmente é desenhado com o sentido positivo do `x` indo para a direita e o do `y` para cima. Assim sendo, se você desenhar isso num papel e girar o papel colocando-o sobre o chão com o eixo `x` virado para a sua frente, o eixo `y` vai ficar apontando para a sua esquerda, e portanto o `y` seria a distância que você seguiria para a esquerda (ou para a direita se for negativo). É importante que seja dessa forma, pois os ângulos com as coordenadas polares são medidos a partir do eixo `x` e giram em direção ao eixo `y` chegando nele ao atingir 90 graus. Com esse sistema de coordenadas que temos, os ângulos positivos seriam então expressos no sentido anti-horário, ou seja, girando para a esquerda (e os ângulos negativos seriam para a direita, no sentido horário).

Enfim, para converter as coordenadas cartesianas para polares e obter o *teta* (ou seja, θ) é onde o `atan2` entra:

> [image: e]
>   [image: f]
>   [image: g] (desprezando-se aquele erro de cerca de 1 cm vez que não é exatamente 433 metros)

Esse [image: h] é uma medida em radianos.

Convertendo para graus:

> [image: i]

Ou seja, 60 graus girando para a esquerda.

Dito isso, vamos ver o seu código:

```
float getAngle() { 
  return atan2(height-mouseY, mouseX);
}
```

A origem do sistema é o pixel no canto **superior esquerdo**. Assim sendo, `mouseX` é a distância (na horizontal) da borda esquerda da tela até posição do mouse e `mouseY` é a distância (na vertical) da borda superior da tela até a posição do mouse.

No entanto, temos que notar que o sentido positivo do `y` na tela não é para cima, e sim para baixo. Isso vai fazer com que as coordenadas polares girem para a direita ao invés de ser para a esquerda.

Esse `height-mouseY` é interessante. Imagine um segmento de reta vertical cortando a tela da borda superior à borda inferior e passando pelo ponto onde o mouse está. Esse ponto dividirá esse segmento de reta em duas partes, uma acima e uma abaixo da posição do mouse. O tamanho das duas partes juntas é `height`, que é a altura da tela (que é a distância entre a borda superior e a inferior). O tamanho da parte acima da posição do mouse é igual a distância entre a borda superior e essa posição, ou seja, `mouseY`. Logo, o tamanho da parte abaixo dessa posição é o tamanho total menos o tamanho da parte de cima, ou seja `height-mouseY`.

O que `height-mouseY` ser a parte de baixo significa? Significa que essa é a distância entre a posição do mouse e a borda **inferior** da tela. Isso é um truque para mover a origem para o canto **inferior** esquerdo ao invés do canto **superior** esquerdo. No entanto, esse truque gera um efeito colateral que é o de inverter o sentido do eixo `y`, afinal de contas, o sinal de `mouseY` está negativo, e portanto o sentido dele está invertido. Isso faz com que o novo `y` resultante dessa transformação novamente aponte para cima e faz com que os ângulos das coordenadas polares voltem a girar para a esquerda.

Com isso aplicamos o `atan2`. Ele vai dar a direção entre o canto inferior esquerdo da tela e a posição do mouse em radianos, considerando que o ângulo zero seria aquele onde o mouse está sobre a borda inferior.

Se o ponto de origem está no canto inferior esquerdo, então, a menos que o mouse pudesse estar fora da tela, não há como ele estar abaixo e nem à esquerda do ponto de origem, ele necessariamente tem que estar acima e à direita (ou no máximo na mesma linha, seja na horizontal ou na vertical). Considerando que o ângulo zero seria aquele sobre a borda inferior (reto para à direita a partir da origem) e que as coordenadas estão girando para a esquerda, temos que 90 graus será o ângulo sobre a borda esquerda da tela (reto para cima a partir da origem). Isso significa que qualquer que seja o ângulo resultante de qualquer ponto dentro da tela, ele estará entre 0 e 90 graus. Ou se preferir, entre 0 e π/2 radianos.

Para finalizar, ainda há um caso interessante: Se o mouse estiver exatamente no canto inferior esquerdo, temos que o ângulo formado entre o canto inferior esquerdo e a posição do mouse é... indeterminado! Não dá para calcular um ângulo entre dois pontos se esses dois pontos na verdade forem um só! É aí que os casos especiais entram. Isso provavelmente vai cair no segundo caso especial e resultar em +0.

Comment: Resumindo, eu uso atan2 quando eu não tenho nenhum angulo?

Comment: @find83 Mais ou menos isso. Você usa o `atan2` para descobrir qual é o ângulo. Se você estiver precisando descobrir isso, é porque deve ser uma informação que você já não tinha antes.

Comment: O que é "zero positivo" e "zero negativo"? Pelo fato de ser zero, não significa que não tem sinal, que é neutro?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260685/28595