# O que é "zero positivo" e "zero negativo" em tipos float e double?

Tags: java, ponto-flutuante

Na resposta [**deste link**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260510/28595) é explicado o funcionamento do método [`atan2()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-), e na sua tradução da documentação feita pelo [Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132/victor-stafusa), há alguns trechos que destaco abaixo:

> (...)
>
> - Se o primeiro argumento é zero positivo e o segundo argumento é positivo, ou o primeiro argumento é positivo e finito e o segundo argumento é infinito positivo, então o resultado é zero positivo.
> - Se o primeiro argumento é zero negativo e o segundo argumento é positivo, ou o primeiro argumento é negativo e finito e o segundo argumento é infinito positivo, então o resultado é zero negativo.
>
> (...)

Essa explicação de zero positivo e zero negativo se refere aos parâmetros recebidos pelo método citado, que são do tipo `double`.

Sempre entendi que "*zero*" representa um ponto neutro no sistema numérico, então não entendo como algo neutro pode possuir sinal.

O que significa *"zero positivo"* e *"zero negativo"* e por quê usam sinais para tipos com ponto flutuante em Java?

Comment: Acho que isso é porque com pontos flutuantes, nenhum valor é exato. Então quando você acha que tem zero, na verdade você tem um valor que tende a zero.

Comment: Hj eu fui no banco e vi q o Dow Jones tinha oscilado NaN%. Fiquei impressionado :)

Comment: Estou quase certo que isso se refere ao IEEE 754 e não é uma questão com o Java, inclusive tem duas respostas no site sobre isto, mas não consigo achar.

Comment: @Maniero "*Hello, undefined, congratulations for you NaNth birthday!*"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Onde `float` e `double` são especificados

O `float` e o `double` são implementados de acordo com o [padrão IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), usado por praticamente todas as linguagens de programação modernas que trabalham com números de ponto flutuante de 32 ou 64 bits.

## A representação interna do `float`

O `float` é representado com 32 bits dessa forma (imagem da wikipedia):

> [image: a]

Observe o primeiro bit, ele é o bit de sinal. Se for 0 é um número positivo, se for 1 é negativo. De forma que o valor do `float` é o seguinte:

> (a) [image: -1^sign x (1 + fraction/2^23) x 2^(expoent - 127)], se o *expoent* for diferente de 0 e de 255.
>
> (b) [image: -1^sign x fraction/2^23 x 2^-126], se o *expoent* for igual a 0.
>
> (c) [image: fórmula +inf], se o *expoent* for igual a 255 e o *fraction* for igual a 0.
>
> (d) NaN, se o *expoent* for igual a 255 e o *fraction* diferente de 0.

Os valores da equação (a) são aqueles que são denominados de números de ponto flutuante normais, enquanto que os da equação (b) são denominados de números de ponto flutuante subnormais ou denormais. Já os valores do (c) são os de infinidade e (d) é NaN (*not-a-number*).

Vemos ver o que a fórmula (a) está multiplicando. São três diferentes termos:

- A parte do [image: sinal] será 1 ou −1.
- A parte do [image: 2^(expoent - 127)] será sempre uma potência de 2.
- Na parte do [image: fraction/2^23], uma vez que *fraction* tem 23 bits, então ele está entre 0 e [image: 2^23-1]. Dessa forma esse termo terá um valor [image: x] tal que [image: 1<x<=2].

No caso (a), vê-se que não é possível que nenhum dos termos multiplicados resulte em zero, logo, não é possível haver um valor zero aqui.

A equação do (b) é semelhante a do (a). A diferença está que o expoente mantido é o mesmo do menor valor possível do caso (a), sendo usado −126 ao invés de −127. Mas os valores são diferentes porque aquele 1 não é mais somado ao segundo termo. O segundo termo no caso (b), é diferente, será sempre um valor [image: x] tal que [image: 0<x<=1].

Assim sendo, quando o *expoent* é zero e o *fraction* também é zero, a equação (b) vai resultar em zero. Mas o bit do sinal ainda está lá, dando duas representações possíveis ao valor zero. Também temos diversos valores que resultam em *NaN* ([image: 2^52 - 1] desses valores para ser exato).

Eis aqui um teste para mostrar os dois zeros:

```
class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float a = Float.intBitsToFloat(0);
        float b = Float.intBitsToFloat(0b1000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
0.0
-0.0
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/Vr3NXx)

## A representação interna do `double`

Ainda temos o `double` que usa um conceito semelhante, mas com mais bits e valores diferentes:

> [image: b]

As equações do `double` são essas:

> (a) [image: -1^sign x (1 + fraction/2^52) x 2^(expoent - 1023)], se o *expoent* for diferente de 0 e de 2047.
>
> (b) [image: -1^sign x fraction/2^52 x 2^-1022], se o *expoent* for igual a 0.
>
> (c) [image: fórmula +inf], se o *expoent* for igual a 2047 e o *fraction* for igual a 0.
>
> (d) NaN, se o *expoent* for igual a 2047 e o *fraction* diferente de 0.

## Por que existe o +0.0 e o −0.0?

Você ainda pergunta o porquê de terem feito tal coisa. A resposta é que é para que o sinal fosse preservado quando um cálculo com números de ponto flutuante chegasse em um valor tão pequeno que perdesse todos os bits de significância, mesmo assim o sinal fosse preservado, diferenciando então um valor negativo que foi arredondado para zero de um valor positivo que foi arredondado para zero.

Por exemplo:

```
class Teste2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float a = Float.intBitsToFloat(5);
        float pinf = Float.intBitsToFloat(0b0111_1111__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000);
        float ninf = Float.intBitsToFloat(0b1111_1111__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000);
        float b = a / pinf;
        float c = a / ninf;
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
0.0
-0.0
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/zzDe0P)

## Como os valores +0.0, −0.0 e NaN são comparados?

E para finalizar, temos que +0.0 e −0.0 são valores iguais, ao passo que um valor NaN nunca é igual a nada (nem a ele mesmo):

```
class Teste3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float zeroPositivo = Float.intBitsToFloat(0);
        float zeroNegativo = Float.intBitsToFloat(0b1000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0000);
        System.out.println(zeroPositivo == zeroNegativo);
        System.out.println(zeroPositivo != zeroNegativo);
        float nan1 = Float.intBitsToFloat(0b1111_1111__1000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0001);
        float nan2 = Float.intBitsToFloat(0b1111_1111__1000_0000__0000_0000__0000_0010);
        System.out.println(nan1 == nan2);
        System.out.println(nan1 == nan1);
        System.out.println(nan1 != nan2);
        System.out.println(nan1 != nan1);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
true
false
false
false
true
true
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/3OZGbe)

Essa saída significa que o `==` considera que o +0.0 e o −0.0 têm o mesmo valor, não importando o fato de os valores dos bits diferirem.

Por outro lado, quando um dos valores comparados com `==` for algum tipo de NaN, então o resultado sempre é falso, mesmo se um valor NaN estiver sendo comparado com ele mesmo.

O operador `==` sempre retorna o oposto do que o `!=` retorna. Isso significa que um valor NaN é sempre diferente dele mesmo e de todos os outros NaNs.

## Fontes

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Answer (score 10):

A linguagem de programação Java usa o [padrão IEEE 754](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) para aritmética de ponto flutuante que define -0.0 e quando deve ser usado.

> O número mais pequeno representável não tem 1 bit no significado
>   subnormal e é chamado de zero positivo ou negativo conforme
>   determinado pelo sinal. Realmente representa um arredondamento para
>   zero de números no intervalo entre zero e o menor número não-zero
>   representável do mesmo sinal, razão pela qual ele tem um sinal e por
>   que o recíproco + Infinito ou -Infinito também possui um sinal.

Você pode contornar problemas específicos adicionando 0.0

por exemplo:

```
Double.toString(value + 0.0);
```

Veja mais sobre [complexidade de números flutuantes](http://www.programgo.com/article/4441958781/)

Resumidamente

> "-0.0" é produzido quando uma operação de ponto flutuante resulta em
>   um número de ponto flutuante negativo tão próximo de 0 que não pode
>   ser representado normalmente. E "+0.0" também é produzido quando uma
>   operação de ponto flutuante resulta em um número de ponto flutuante 
>   positivo tão próximo de 0 que também não pode ser representado normalmente

A respeito de operações, em aplicações pode ser uma fonte de erros, se o desenvolvedor não levar em conta que enquanto as duas representações de zero se comportam como iguais sob comparações numéricas, pode produzir resultados diferentes em algumas operações.