# Que tipo de dados (double, float) eu devo usar ao representar uma temperatura?

Tags: java, tipagem, float, double

Minha dúvida é em relação ao uso do `Double` e do `Float` em exercícios de Java ao ter que declarar uma temperatura (escala Celsius). Qual deles devo usar nesse caso?

Eu declarei como `Double`, porém a professora ao corrigir o exercício em classe acabou usando o `Float`.

Sei que entre esses dois dados a diferença é a precisão que eles apresentam, mas o que ainda não consegui entender é quando cada um deles, e para quais fins o `Double` e o `Float` são usados.

Comment: você pode encontrar uma ótima explicação [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219211/qual-a-forma-correta-de-usar-os-tipos-float-double-e-decimal/219465).

Comment: obrigada gabriel!

Comment: Eu acho que vale a pena perguntar para a professora porque float está "errado" nesse caso. A princípio, temperaturas não exigem uma precisão tão grande que um float não possa suportar. A menos que haja algum outro detalhe no exercício que "obrigue" a usar double (ou que faça ele ser a melhor escolha). Mas parece que vc está usando os wrappers (**D**ouble e **F**loat, com letra maiúscula), pode ser que isso tenha a ver com a resposta. Se quiser **[edit]** a pergunta colocando mais detalhes, como o trecho de código por exemplo, quem sabe podemos dar mais detalhes sobre este caso específico

Comment: E depois de perguntar pra professora, comente aqui o que ela disse, que é pra gente ver se tem fundamento mesmo. Não duvidando dela, lógico, mas só pra ficar do lado "seguro". Já vi muito professor (de faculdade renomada, inclusive) que claramente só leu teoria, mas nunca teve que fazer nada "real", pelo tipo de aula dada.

Comment: @hkotsubo Julgo que entendeu mal pois *"a professora ao corrigir o exercicio em classe acabou usando o `Float`! "*

Comment: @ramaral É mesmo, que distração a minha. Mesmo assim, qualquer um dos tipos serviria e continua sendo estranho que um deles esteja "errado" e precise ser "corrigido". A menos que haja algum detalhe no exercício que "obrigue" a usar float.

Comment: @hkotsubo Nada obriga, no entanto há justificação para escolher `float` conforme explicado na resposta do Manieiro e do Victor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não existe um tipo específico adequado, para este caso alguns podem ser usados.

Na verdade, se for criar tipos para lidar com essas temperaturas e for usar uma infraestrutura sofisticada para representá-los, o tipo interno que guardará os números importa pouco. Poderia usar algumas estratégias e depende do que espera realizar. Pode até que ser que um simples `float` resolva fácil.

Se for usar um tipo genérico para representar pode até usar um `int`, mas provavelmente o mais fácil seja usar um `float` que já tem a parte decimal. Com um `int` teria que fazer sempre uma divisão para pegar a parte decimal, fazer contas para adequar a escala que estiver usando, tem que ter vários cuidados e não deve valer a pena pra uso básico, e para uso mais sofisticado acho que a solução anterior é melhor.

Nada impede usar um `double`, mas acho exagero para este tipo de coisa. O `float` economiza memória e tem precisão mais que suficiente pra algo simples assim. Não dá para dizer que está errado, mas não seria a primeira escolha.

A diferença entre eles é só a precisão mesmo, o que obviamente faz o mais preciso ser maior (8 bytes contra 4). Não confundir com exatidão.

Se tivesse no enunciado para usar algo que ocupa menos espaço, poderia até pensarem outras coisas, ainda mais se tiver exigência de exatidão. Me parece que nada disso é exigido, aí `float` é melhor em uso real, mas dá para argumentar que o `double` não faz mal a não ser ocupar memória a toa, que muda pouco na maioria dos casos.

Neste caso duvido que o [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) seja necessário, mas só você pode responder se deve ter exatidão além da precisão que o `float` já dá. Veja mais em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 11):

Deixa eu copiar algumas coisas que postei [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260701/132):

> O `float` e o `double` são implementados de acordo com o [padrão IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), usado por praticamente todas as linguagens de programação modernas que trabalham com números de ponto flutuante de 32 ou 64 bits.
>
> O `float` é representado com 32 bits dessa forma (imagem da wikipedia):
>
> > [image: a]
>
> Observe o primeiro bit, ele é o bit de sinal. Se for 0 é um número positivo, se for 1 é negativo. De forma que o valor do `float` é o seguinte:
>
> > (a) [image: -1^sign x (1 + fraction/2^23) x 2^(expoent - 127)], se o *expoent* for diferente de 0 e de 255.
> >
> > (b) [image: -1^sign x fraction/2^23 x 2^-126], se o *expoent* for igual a 0.
> >
> > (c) [image: fórmula +inf], se o *expoent* for igual a 255 e o *fraction* for igual a 0.
> >
> > (d) NaN, se o *expoent* for igual a 255 e o *fraction* diferente de 0.
>
> Os valores da equação (a) são aqueles que são denominados de números de ponto flutuante normais, enquanto que os da equação (b) são denominados de números de ponto flutuante subnormais ou denormais. Já os valores do (c) são os de infinidade e (d) é NaN (*not-a-number*).

> Ainda temos o `double` que usa um conceito semelhante, mas com mais bits e valores diferentes:
>
> > [image: b]
>
> As equações do `double` são essas:
>
> > (a) [image: -1^sign x (1 + fraction/2^52) x 2^(expoent - 1023)], se o *expoent* for diferente de 0 e de 2047.
> >
> > (b) [image: -1^sign x fraction/2^52 x 2^-1022], se o *expoent* for igual a 0.
> >
> > (c) [image: fórmula +inf], se o *expoent* for igual a 2047 e o *fraction* for igual a 0.
> >
> > (d) NaN, se o *expoent* for igual a 2047 e o *fraction* diferente de 0.

Pois bem, o `double` tem uma capacidade de armazenagem maior do que o `float` tanto no expoente quanto na mantissa (*fraction*). Assim sendo, todo valor `float` pode ser representado por um `double`, mas o contrário não é verdadeiro. Logo, a pergunta a ser feita é se o `float` oferece precisão suficiente.

O `float` tem 23 bits para representar o *fraction*. Isso é suficiente para armazenar números inteiros mantendo o *expoent* em 0 nos valores entre 0 até 2<sup>24</sup> - 1 = 16777215. Para representar o 16777217, ele perde o bit 1 menos significativo arredondando para 16777216.

Isso significa que números com precisão de 0.5 pode ser armazenados até 8388607.5. Com precisão de 0.25, é até 4194303.75. Mantendo-se uma precisão suficiente para representar 3 casas após o ponto decimal (com precisão 1/1024), dá para representar números até 16383.999.

Representar números que representam temperaturas com precisão de milésimos de graus até uma temperatura de mais de 16000 graus, mostra que o `float` tem precisão suficiente para isso. Assim sendo, tanto o `float` quanto o `double` podem ser utilizados.