# Como os computadores armazenam e interpretam números de ponto flutuante em binário?

Tags: matemática, ciência-da-computação, ponto-flutuante, números-binários

No meu curso de análise e desenvolvimento de sistemas comecei a matéria de matemática computacional o assunto era bases numéricas e conversões, algo que me chamou atenção é que eles estavam também representando números binários com vírgula como por exemplo: `1010,01` e também fazendo sua conversão para números decimais para nosso sistema numérico, porém nunca vi em lugar nenhum números binários de ponto flutuante, e na calculadora do Windows no modo programador a vírgula nem esta habilitada para números binários.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade isso não existe e não faz muito sentido. O que o pessoa faz é separar as partes inteira e decimal com uma vírgula, mas no computador não é assim que esses números são representados. A notação binária foi criada para indicar como é o *layout* físico do dado no computador, portanto como fica cada bit na memória que represente um número.

O ponto flutuante não tem parte inteira e parte decimal, ele é um número que possui um sinal, uma mantissa e um expoente, mas como uma coisa só, assim:

[image: Representação de um double]

Para o computador é isso que interessa e é eficiente assim. Não tem separação, quando você vê na tela está apenas recebendo uma representação textual de algo que é mostrado de forma decimal e aí sim tem um vírgula para dar indicação de grandeza.

Eu sei que tem umas pessoas que inventaram essa maluquice de representar um número como binário sem ser binário, mas isso não faz sentido e por isso coisas reais (calculadora do Windows) não vão dar crédito a isso.

Mesmo outras formas de representar parte inteira e decimal não usam vírgula como representação interna, a vírgula é um conceito humano para números decimais.

Se quiser mais detalhes [tem uma resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260701/101). Ou [pode ver na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).