# Formatar números corretamente em Java

Tags: java, number-format

Estou tentando usar o `NumberFormat` para formatar alguns valores em Java mas ele sempre retorna o valor arredondado. Já pesquisei bastante para ver se consigo fazer isso não acontecer, mas não achei nada a respeito.

Código:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
System.out.println(formatter.format(10000999999999999999100.69d));
```

Output:

```
10.001.000.000.000.000.000.000
```

Gostaria que ele retornasse o valor correto sem arredondar tipo de baixo:

```
10.000.999.999.999.999.999.100.69d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A causa do problema

O seu problema é mais embaixo. Por exemplo, veja isso:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 10000999999999999999100.69d;
        double b = 10001000000000000000000d;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(a == b);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
1.0001E22
true
```

[Veja aqui isso executando no ideone.](https://ideone.com/m0GmfD)

O que ocorre é que o seu número foi arredondado para ser armazenado no `double`. No seu caso, o `double` não tem a precisão suficiente para armazenar o seu número ([veja mais aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260701/132)). Quanto maior a magnitude do número, menor é a precisão do `double`. O `double` tem uma precisão de 52 bits. O que significa que números que precisam de mais do que 52 bits para serem armazenados, serão arredondados de alguma forma.

Para saber exatamente como o seu `double` está sendo armazenado, podemos fazer isso:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 10000999999999999999100.69d;
        String x = Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(a));
        while (x.length() < 64) {
            x = "0" + x;
        }
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
0100010010000000111100010011111000001100000000110111001011001101
```

[Veja aqui isso rodando no ideone.](https://ideone.com/Ph60yG)

O que esse padrão significa?

- `0` - Número positivo.
- `10001001000` - Expoente. Isso é 8 + 64 + 1024 = 1096. Há um viés de 1023 (deve-se subtrair 1023), e portanto o expoente é 1096 - 1023 = 73.
- `0000111100010011111000001100000000110111001011001101` - A fração é 265.248.791.818.957
- Ou seja, isso é:

> (1 + (265.248.791.818.957 / 2<sup>52</sup>)) * 2<sup>73</sup>
>   2<sup>73</sup> + (265.248.791.818.957 / 2<sup>52</sup>) * 2<sup>73</sup>
>   2<sup>73</sup> + (265.248.791.818.957 / 2<sup>52</sup>) * 2<sup>52</sup> * 2<sup>21</sup>
>   2<sup>73</sup> + 265.248.791.818.957 * 2<sup>21</sup>
>   2<sup>73</sup> + 265.248.791.818.957 * 2.097.152
>   9.444.732.965.739.290.427.392 + 556.267.034.260.709.310.464
>   10.000.999.999.999.999.737.856

Ok, o número final representado é 10.000.999.999.999.999.737.856. Então porque o que apareceu foi o 10.001.000.000.000.000.000.000? A resposta é porque, como já deu para perceber, houve **perda de precisão** no número armazenado. Assim sendo, considerando que houve essa perda, existem vários números diferentes que serão apresentados como se fossem iguais. E então, o algoritmo que mostra o `double` como uma string, procura produzir na string, o valor que tenha a representação decimal mais redonda dentre os possíveis números que a produzirão, e não a representação do valor nominal exato.

Quais são esses vários números que gerarão essa representação? Podemos somar 1 a fração lá em cima e refazer o cálculo para achar o próximo valor representável, que é 10.001.000.000.000.001.835.008. A diferença é de 2.097.152 = 2<sup>73-52</sup> = 2<sup>21</sup>. Isso também mostra que pela grande magnitude do número, a precisão do `double` para essa faixa de números já está tão reduzida que a diferença entre dois valores distinguíveis é de 2.097.152.

Considerando que números podem ser arredondados para cima ou para baixo e que o valor nominal é o centro da faixa de valores que ele representa, logo, a margem de erro para cada lado é de 1.048.576 a partir do valor nominal (1.048.576 = 2.097.152 / 2). Há também uma preferência para o número com a fração par no caso do número estar equidistante entre dois pontos representáveis. Com isso, temos que todos os valores `x` tal que 10.000.999.999.999.998.689.280 < x < 10.001.000.000.000.000.786.432 são representados da mesma forma num `double` e portanto indistinguíveis. Desses, o número 10.001.000.000.000.000.000.000 é o que tem a representação decimal mais redonda. E o seu número 10.000.999.999.999.999.999.100,69 está dentro dessa faixa.

## Como resolver

É só usar a classe [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Abandone o `double` se você quer precisão arbitrária. Também use a classe [`DecimalFormatSumbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) junto com a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Eis o código:

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
        var s = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        s.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        s.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(s);
        var numero = new BigDecimal("10000999999999999999100.69");
        System.out.println(formatter.format(numero));
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
10.000.999.999.999.999.999.100,69
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](https://ideone.com/Z0xr2H)