# Raiz Quadrada com dizima periódica

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Quando tentamos executar o código acima, em raiz de 2, ele trava e não executa, pois possui uma dizima periódica, levando em consideração que podemos receber um número aproximado como resposta da raiz de 2, faça esses exemplo funcionar. apresentando a resposta em código se possível, ou de forma explicativa.

meu código

```
def raiz2(num, menor, maior):
    media = (menor + maior) / 2
    rm = media * media
    if rm == num:
        return media
    elif rm > num:
        return raiz2(num, menor, media)
    else:
        return raiz2(num, media, maior)


def raiz(num, menor, maior):
    r1 = menor * menor
    r2 = maior * maior
    if r1 == num:
        return menor
    elif r2 == num:
        return maior
    elif num > r1 and num < r2:
        return raiz2(num, menor, maior)
        
    else:
        return raiz(num, menor + 1, maior + 1)


def RQ(N):
    return raiz(N, 0, 1)


N = float(input("Digite o valor: "))
print(RQ(N))

print("FIM")
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema que está ocorrendo no programa não é "dízima periódica" e sim,
um problema de representação de números do tipo ponto flutuante (*float*)
na memória do computador e como eles são comparados.

Mais especificamente, quando você compara 2 números *float* (após o cálculo
da média e do quadrado):

```
if rm == num:
```

O resultado desta comparação para encontrar a raiz quadrada de 2 sempre será
falsa, pois esse resultado é um número irracional (e não uma dízima).

Se você imprimir esses valores, verá que eles estão próximos:

```
rm=1.9999999999999996
num=2.0
```

Mas não são e não serão iguais, portanto, a recursão não termina e o programa "trava".

Você encontrará ótimas explicações sobre o porquê isto acontece nas respostas
das perguntas abaixo:

[Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219211/qual-a-forma-correta-de-usar-os-tipos-float-double-e-decimal)

[O que é "zero positivo" e "zero negativo" em tipos float e double?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260685/o-que-%c3%a9-zero-positivo-e-zero-negativo-em-tipos-float-e-double)

ou em inglês:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Como você está utilizando um algoritmo parecido com o [Método da bisseção](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_da_bisse%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
para encontrar a raiz, uma possibilidade para solucionar o problema é você
definir um erro absoluto (ou tolerância **TOL**), e quando a diferença
absoluta entre rm e num for menor que esse erro, você retorna o valor
`media`:

```
ϵ = 0.0001

se ǀrm - numǀ < ϵ; raiz2 = media
```

Porém:

1. o resultado precisa ser arredondado de acordo com o valor da tolerância,
   para que não ocorra o mesmo problema (de ponto flutuante);
2. a tolerância precisa ser um pouco maior do que a precisão que você pretende
   imprimir o resultado, para evitar erros de arredondamento

Uma forma de implementar esta alteração no seu programa sem utilizar nenhuma
biblioteca é:

```
# Número de casas decimais de precisão
DECIMAIS = 6
# Aumento na precisão
PRECISAO = 2
# Define a tolerância. Neste exemplo: 1e-8
TOL = 10**-(DECIMAIS+PRECISAO)

def raiz2(....):
    ...    
    if abs(rm - num) < TOL:
        return media
```

e ao final do algoritmo, para imprimir o resultado correto:

```
N = float(input("Digite o valor: "))
resultado = RQ(N)
print(f"{resultado:.{DECIMAIS+PRECISAO}f}"[:-PRECISAO])
print("FIM")
```

---

No Python, a biblioteca **math** já tem uma função que ajusta a comparação de
números ponto flutuantes e a implementação fica muito mais simples:

```
import math

def raiz2(....):
    ...    
    if math.isclose(rm, num):
        return media
```

A função *isclose()* verifica se os 2 números estão "próximos" (conforme a teoria
dos números ponto flutuante) e retorna verdadeiro, caso estejam.

Também, é possível definir a tolerância nesta função (consulte a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) da
função).

Porém, o ajuste para imprimir o resultado sem erros de arredondamento, também é
necessário.

Caso você precise de uma precisão maior no resultado, você pode utilizar a
biblioteca [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

---

#### Importante

Independente da implementação que você for utilizar, a representação dos
números ponto flutuante na memória tem um limite e, caso você ultrapasse
este limite, o problema de recursão **irá ocorrer**.