# Javascript (puro) - Encontrar ângulo exato de triângulo de acordo com a tabela de razões trigonométricas

Tags: javascript, matemática

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de encontrar o ângulo exato de um triângulo sem depender da tabela.

[image: Tablea de razões trigonométricas]

No meu programa, estou pegando o valor em radiano e transformando em graus, porém o valor não condiz com o da tabela.

O meu triângulo possui 233.5px de altura e 180 de largura. Ao realizar o seno, encontro um ângulo de 45, mas na tabela seria 52. E o ângulo que preciso encontrar é o da tabela. O motivo da pergunta é que devo chegar à esses valores por meio do programa pois não posso defini-los.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `atan2` para isso. Teste abaixo:

```js
console.log(Math.atan2(233.5, 180) * 180 / Math.PI);
```

A saída no console é "52.37216305431494". Como você deve saber, o `* 180 / Math.PI` é para converter a resposta de radianos para graus.

Note que os parâmetros de `atan2` são o `y` primeiro e depois o `x`. No seu caso, `y` é a altura do triângulo (233.5) e `x` é a largura (180).

Para entender como funciona a função `atan2`, veja [**essa outra pergunta que respondi**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260508/132).

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado mesmo mano! Funcionou perfeitamente aqui, só vou dar uma lida lá para entender o porquê. :)

Comment: @PedroLucasFlor Só uma observação, na sua pergunta você falou em "233.5px" de altura. Se você está buscando esse valor pelo atributo algum elemento exibido no browser é muito provável que receba um arrendondamento e isso influencia no resultado.